# How do I deal with Error stated below?

Tags: pymongo

I am performing a pymongo experiment.

Query: To add the article

jess@ubuntu:~/pymongo/pymongo$      python pymongo_assg.py --add_articles '{"text":"abc","title":"hi","author":"xyz","tags":"mongo,test","image":"/home/jess/pymongo/pymongo/index.png"}'

Respective Error:

usage: pymongo_assg.py [-h] [--get_articles] [--add_article ADD_ARTICLE]
pymongo_assg.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --add_articles {"text":"abc","title":"hi","author":"xyz","tags":"mongo,test","image":"/home/jess/pymongo/pymongo/index.png"}

Comment: You use `--add_articles` (plural) where the program expects `--add_article` (singular).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the error message.
You should use --add_article instead of --add_articles.